# How can I get my custom field type (lookup) to render in list view on SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, custom-field-type

I have a custom field type that was built for SharePoint 2010 that I have installed on SharePoint 2013 Foundation. The wsp installed perfectly and I get all the same functionality.

The one problem I am having is how the information is displayed in the list view. I am inheriting an SPFieldLookup and am not doing anything to override how this is displayed in the list view.

On SharePoint 2010 it renders perfectly as a hyperlink to the item which opens the standard pop out window on click etc. On SharePoint 2013 Foundation however the html doesn't render properly at all- it is almost as though it is displaying as plain text.

SharePoint 2010:

[image: SP2010]

SharePoint 2013 Foundation:

[image]

My question is how can I get the lookup value to render properly on SharePoint 2013?

The same version of the wsp in installed on both machines.

Unsure as to whether this was simply a browser or client side issue I added a standard lookup field to the list and it renders fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SP 2013 by default field rendering is done on client side. Concept of JSLink has been introduced if you want to change the look and feel of field.
However by ClientRender=False in new form url you can force it to server render mode.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with my codeplex project which is based on Lookup field. I added a link to dummy JS file and overrode the JSLink property of the field class. I have blogged about it here: http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2013/12/sharepoint-2013-upgrade-sharepoint-2010.html

Answer (score 0):

So after an afternoon of head scratching it turns out that this is not a deployment issue. It probably didn't even warrant a question but for anyone who has the same problem as me...

If you edit the page and modify the listview settings you will see that there is a new setting called "Server Render".

[image]

I guess this ultimately gives you more control but in may case it prevented my fields from rendering as expected- turning this on meant my custom fields we once again displayed 'normally'.